# Meta Query compare with LIKE pulls similar post types: 55 and 155, and 1,155

Tags: query, meta-query

In my admin I have a CPT called Artists, and another one named Exhibits. I connect exhibits to artists via a relationship field in the exhibition cpt.

I setup a query on the artist page to pull the connected exhibits, but I am running into an issue where extra post types are being pulled. For example the ID of the exhibition is 55. But I am getting matches with exhibit 155, 1055m etc, Anything with 55 in it.

Any ideas?

```
//get current artist post ID.
$id = get_the_ID();

$args = array(
    'numberposts'     => -1,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'orderby'         => 'date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'post_type'       => 'exhibitions',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'artists',
            'value' => $id,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: note that if you use a taxonomy named `artists` for this, you avoid this issue, _and you gain a **massive** performance boost_. `meta_query` is inherently slow, and querying inside serialised structured data stored as strings has major downsides such as this. Sadly there is no reliable solution for this problem, only mitigations and work arounds for special edge cases. You should also edit your question to include how the `artists` field is being set, e.g is it a csv value? serialised PHP? JSON?